# Slow image loading from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm creating a small MERN stack app (using Atlas database) where users can upload multiple images and then view them in some sort of gallery.

Currently, I upload images using GridFS.

The problem is that when I try to get for instance a single image from the database it takes too much time until I get a response: about a second for a small 200x200 picture when usually it takes 50 ms or even less.

Here is my route for getting an image:

```
router.get('/photo/single/:filename', (req, res) => {
  const bucket = new mongoose.mongo.GridFSBucket(mongoose.connection.db, {
    chunkSizeBytes: 1024,
    bucketName: 'uploads'
  })

  bucket
    .openDownloadStreamByName(req.params.filename).pipe(res)
})
```

Not much code here as you can see.

So why does `openDownloadStreamByName` work so slow in my case? Is it just because I'm using a free M0 cluster or I'm just missing something in my route? Or maybe storing images in MongoDB is not a good idea by itself (but I don't see another solution since in my case images can weight more that 16MB)?

Comment: storing large images in database is not a recommended approach. you should save image in local directory or you could use a cloud storage service and save the path in database.

Answer (score 1):

I gave up on the idea of storing files in MongoDB. Instead, I've created a bucket on AWS S3 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please  store images and other binary data in MongoDB Atlas using [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/).

Comment: `Currently, I upload images using GridFS.`, Pretty sure he's already doing so...